# Java RestTemplate error

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to call this method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="v1/sendemail")
    public ResponseEntity sendPasswordResetEmail (@RequestParam("name")     final String name,
                                       @RequestParam("password") final String password,
                                       @RequestParam("email")    final String email)
    {
        final boolean success = notificationService.sendPasswordResetEmail(name, password, email);
        return success ?
                new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

I am trying to call it in three different ways, but none of them worked:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> auth = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
ResponseEntity<String> auth2 = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class, (Object[]) null);
ResponseEntity<String> auth3 = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, ResponseEntity.class, new Object());
```

This is the error I get:

```
"status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request",
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

URL:http://localhost:9093/v1/sendemail

Entity:

```
<{password=H1!zsaddd486, name=John, email=john@gmail.com},{token=[token], API_KEY=[something], API_SECRET=[something]}>
```

Comment: what is your 'url' and 'entity'? At least in last call you pass new Object in place where parameters should be

Comment: @freakman code updated. Thanks

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logs on your Server and check what Spring tells you.

Comment: Also, what kind of `HttpEntity` is that? Show us how you created it.